# Is Java RegExp group negation possible?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regexp: `(["'])(\\\1|[^\1])+\1`

Obviously it could not be compiled because `[^\1]` is illeagal.

Is it possible to negate a matched group?

Comment: What is the text you are trying to match? Your regex is a bit confusing.

Comment: The question is, is it possible in other flavours/languages? I could imagine that such a construct does not make sense as a capture group can contain more than one character, so `[^\1]` would be a list of these characters... but this is just my opinion. It might also simply be that the regex engine has to know *beforehand* which characters to expect. Does `[\1]` work?

Comment: I only found this on [`regular-expression.info`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html): *"Backreferences also cannot be used inside a character class. The `\1` in regex like `(a)[\1b]` will be interpreted as an octal escape in most regex flavors. So this regex will match an `a` followed by either `\x01` or a `b`."* If you want to have more insight into regular expressions, I suggest [*Mastering Regular Expressions* by Jeffrey Friedl](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do).

Comment: The question is: is it possible to negate an already matched group in Java regexp? `[^\1]` was used just to illustrate that I want to negate a group with index `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use backreferences in a positive or negative character class.

But you can achieve what you want using negative [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(["'])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1
```

**Explanation:**

```
(["'])    # Match and remember a quote.
(?:       # Either match...
 \\.      # an escaped character
|         # or
 (?!\1)   # (unless that character is identical to the quote character in \1)
 .        # any character
)*        # any number of times.
\1        # Match the corresponding quote.
```

Comment: You commented on the other question that it would not work. How about `(["'])(\\\1|.)+?\1`? Isn't alternation supposed to be matched from left to right? Or am I missing the problem here? It seems to be ok in JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling: You're right. Moving the parenthesis to the correct place indeed solves the problem. Let's see if we can undelete Ademiban's answer.

Comment: Voted to undelete. Your solution is probably still better as it avoids backtracking.

Comment: @FelixKling: I'm not sure about performance. Instead of backtracking, it needs to do a lookahead at every single position. I guess that's going to be a bit faster than storing backtracking positions on the stack and all that, but probably not that much. I do prefer it because it is more explicit.